# Django Haystack + ElasticSearch Analyzers

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

So basically i am trying to add an analyzer to my Elasticsearch backend in Haystack and so far i have had no luck.

I am trying to query something like this `3/09.0TBOBR.C1` and i get lots of errors. I was told analyzers were the solution to my problem so i tried using the `keyword` analyzer

i tried like this:

```
class ConfigurableElasticBackend(ElasticsearchSearchBackend):

    DEFAULT_ANALYZER = "keyword"
```

and i also tried like this in my settings file:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DEFAULT_ANALYZER = "keyword"
```

I did **REBUILD INDEX** after changing

My error message is:

```
Failed to query Elasticsearch using '(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)':
Non-OK response returned (400):
    u'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;
shardFailures {[oh93DYn1QTyVWmAnDMyKdQ][haystack][4]:
    SearchParseException[[haystack][4]: from[-1],size[-1]:
    Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
        "sort": [{
            "score": {"order": "asc", "ignore_unmapped": true, "missing": "_last"}
        }],
        "query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"fquery": {"query": {"query_string": {"query": "django_ct:(caselaw.process)"}}, "_cache": true}}, "query": {"query_string": {"query": "(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)", "default_operator": "AND", "default_field": "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard": true}}}
        }, "from": 0, "size": 20}]]];

nested:
QueryParsingException[[haystack]
    Failed to parse query [(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)]];
    nested:
    ParseException[Cannot parse \'(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)\':
        Lexical error at line 1, column 17.
        Encountered: <EOF> after : "/09.0TBOBR.C1)"];
    nested:
    TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 17.
        Encountered: <EOF> after : "/09.0TBOBR.C1)"]; }{[oh93DYn1QTyVWmAnDMyKdQ][haystack][0]:
        SearchParseException[[haystack][0]: from[-1],size[-1]:
        Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"sort": [{"score": {"order": "asc", "ignore_unmapped": true, "missing": "_last"}}], "query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"fquery": {"query": {"query_string": {"query": "django_ct:(caselaw.process)"}}, "_cache": true}}, "query": {"query_string": {"query": "(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)", "default_operator": "AND", "default_field": "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard": true}}}}, "from": 0, "size": 20}]]];
    nested:
    QueryParsingException[[haystack] Failed to parse query [(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)]];
    nested:
    ParseException[Cannot parse \'(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)\':
        Lexical error at line 1, column 17.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/09.0TBOBR.C1)"];
    nested:
    TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 17.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/09.0TBOBR.C1)"]; }{[oh93DYn1QTyVWmAnDMyKdQ][haystack][1]: SearchParseException[[haystack][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"sort": [{"score": {"order": "asc", "ignore_unmapped": true, "missing": "_last"}}], "query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"fquery": {"query": {"query_string": {"query": "django_ct:(caselaw.process)"}}, "_cache": true}}, "query": {"query_string": {"query": "(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)", "default_operator": "AND", "default_field": "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard": true}}}}, "from": 0, "size": 20}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[haystack] Failed to parse query [(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse \'(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)\': Lexical error at line 1, column 17.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/09.0TBOBR.C1)"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 17.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/09.0TBOBR.C1)"]; }{[oh93DYn1QTyVWmAnDMyKdQ][haystack][2]: SearchParseException[[haystack][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"sort": [{"score": {"order": "asc", "ignore_unmapped": true, "missing": "_last"}}], "query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"fquery": {"query": {"query_string": {"query": "django_ct:(caselaw.process)"}}, "_cache": true}}, "query": {"query_string": {"query": "(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)", "default_operator": "AND", "default_field": "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard": true}}}}, "from": 0, "size": 20}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[haystack] Failed to parse query [(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse \'(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)\': Lexical error at line 1, column 17.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/09.0TBOBR.C1)"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 17.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/09.0TBOBR.C1)"]; }{[oh93DYn1QTyVWmAnDMyKdQ][haystack][3]: SearchParseException[[haystack][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"sort": [{"score": {"order": "asc", "ignore_unmapped": true, "missing": "_last"}}], "query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"fquery": {"query": {"query_string": {"query": "django_ct:(caselaw.process)"}}, "_cache": true}}, "query": {"query_string": {"query": "(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)", "default_operator": "AND", "default_field": "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard": true}}}}, "from": 0, "size": 20}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[haystack] Failed to parse query [(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse \'(3/09.0TBOBR.C1)\': Lexical error at line 1, column 17.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/09.0TBOBR.C1)"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 17.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/09.0TBOBR.C1)"]; }]'
```

What am i doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Just to be sure: after changing the analyzer, you should reindex your objects before any change is visible. Did you do that?

Comment: oh no i did not... will try now

Comment: @Bjorn should i use like this ELASTICSEARCH_DEFAULT_ANALYZER = "keyword" in my settings file?

Comment: i tried both ways and rebuild index and no luck yet

Comment: `ELASTICSEARCH_DEFAULT_ANALYZER` should do the trick. Did you get the error while rebuilding the index? Or does it pop up when you try to search? If you build the query by hand (using `curl` on the cmd), does it work?

Comment: the error only happens when i search. i haven't tried curl in cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem on the query side with haystack is that it uses the catch-all field flagged by `document=True` in your search index configuration. This field is most probably not analyzed with the keyword analyzer. But you better check that by looking at the output of elasticsearch (this lists the analyzers):

```
http://localhost:9200/<index-name>/?pretty=true
```

In the stack trace you can see:

"default_field": "text"

You might think about having two different search views if you still want to support free text user searches with "normal" input. For your special search of inputs like `3/09.0TBOBR.C1` you might want to use the `.filter()` or `.narrow()` methods of Haystack's `SearchQuerySet` where you can specify the field to search (and that would be the field you use the `keyword` analyzer on, explicitly). For regular text fields you probably do not want to use keyword (== no) analysis.